# Excel array sum with multiple conditions based on named range

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an array formula that looks like this:

```
{=SUMIF(C11:C23,budgets,F11:F23)}
```

What I want it to do is sum cells `F11:F23` where cells `C11:C23` are values within the named range `budgets`.

Right now `budgets` has two values: `10361` and `10300` (these are transaction codes). However, the formula seems to only work for the first code `10361` but not for the second one.

I don't want to use `SUMIFS` because I have multiple worksheets where I would like this array formula to work, and the codes may change so changing them in one place (the named range `budgets`) will make things easier.

Any ideas? I don't know VBA, so was hoping for a formula solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIF():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(budgets,$C$11:$C$23)>0)*$F$11:$F$23)
```

[image]

---

Or you can use this array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(C11:C23,budgets,F11:F23))
```

Being an array it needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! The second answer definitely works for my purposes.

Why did my formula not work? Why is the additional `SUM` necessary?

And, how would I do the converse (that is, NOT in the `budgets` range?)

Comment: The additional sum is what sums up the individual sumif as it iterates, in this case it is doing two separate sumif and adding them together.  For the converse, I believe you will want the SUMPRODUCT() and Change the `>0` to `=0`

Comment: OK, the second formula works!! But I'm still confused as to why it the second `SUM` was necessary --- is there any way you can explain it in more detail? Maybe write out what it's evaluating at each step in your answer?

Comment: Sumif is not and cannot in itself become an array formula that will iterate the criteria.  So you would need to do something like `=SUMIF(cirt1) + SUMIF(Crit2) + ...` which is the same as the array form of `=SUM(SUMIF(allCrit))`  It is the SUM which causes the iteration of the criteria not the SUMIF. @vashts85

Comment: Thank! What about the `COUNTIF` formula? I've used those before, but it seems you have the range and criteria reversed, yet everything works?

Comment: If your criteria is multiple you will still need to wrap it in SUM() as an array or some other array type formula.